# Find shortest path between list of points

Tags: discrete-mathematics, path-connected

B"H

In things like Google maps one can enter a list of locations to go to in order and it gives you the shortest path to take

What I would like to do is take in a list of locations, with no particular order (except for one starting point)  and find the shortest for route that goes through all points

I was thinking of starting at the first location, and finding the distance from it to all other points, then returning the shortest for the first place to go, and repeat the process, but I'm not sure if that's logically correct

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem

Comment: This is "The Travelling Salesman Problem", there is a vast literature, it is believed that there is no efficient algorithm for finding an exact solution when the number of locations is large, but there are algorithms that work well in practice even for fairly large numbers of locations.

Comment: @community what specific part don't you understand?

Comment: "community" is software, not a person, so no point trying to communicate with it, Yackov.

Comment: @gerry if there's no way for me to communicate with it, then it shouldn't communicate with me. Who decides to put that community comment here?

Comment: If you'll click on "Community" it will take you to https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community where you will learn that nobody decides to post that comment. It is done automatically and autonomously by the software. And if you go to https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=comments you will find that the software has been very busy.